# Model is created but can't update with Express, Mongoose, and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Alright so I'm having a problem with updating a model. I can create a Document and it works just fine but when I try to update, I get an error.

```
/Users/User/Sites/project/app.js:182
        a.features.kids = req.body.a.features.kids;
                                           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kids' of undefined
```

The model looks like this:

```
Affiliate = new Schema({
    'name': String,
    'address': String,
    'features': {
        'kids': { type: Boolean, default: false },
     }
});
```

My form fields looks like this. They are used for both creating and updating with extra fields added for updating:

```
<input type="text" name="a[name]" id="a[name]" />
<input type="text" name="a[address]" id="a[address]" />
<input <% if (a.features.kids) { %>checked <% };  %>type="checkbox" name="a[features.kids]" id="a[features.kids]" />
```

Code for creating a new item. This works fine and all the information is added properly:

```
var a = new Affiliate(req.body.a);

a.save(function() {
    res.redirect('/admin');
});
```

Broken code for updating an item:

```
Affiliate.findOne({ _id: req.params.id}, function(err, a) {
    if (!a) return next(new NotFound('Affiliate not found'));
    a.name = req.body.a.name;
    a.address = req.body.a.address;
    a.features.open_gym = req.body.a.features.kids; 

    a.save(function(err) {
        res.redirect('/admin');
    });

});
```

Comment: If you console.log req.body.a, what do you get? Is 'a.name' and 'a.address' the name of the variables?

Comment: logging req.body.a gives me
`{ a: 
   { id: '4e1f803999decab541000003',
     name: 'Name Here',
     address: '1234 Street',
     'features.kids': 'on'} }`
Is there something wrong with how I named my form field for the child?

Comment: I would suggest not using dots in your field id's. For example if you do features_kids it will work fine, as Peter Lyons mentioned below. You end up doing alot of workarounds for very little benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I think the express `bodyParser` is probably not interpreting `a[features.kids]` the way you expect.  You can access the field with `req.body.a['features.kids']` since it's not interpreting that embedded period. Try naming your `<input>`  `a[features][kids]` and see if that parses into the object structure you are expecting.